# how to install numpy for python 3.5 on windows 10 while having both python 2.7 and python 3.5 available?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pip, pydev

I am running with python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed on windows 10. I have also installed pydev in eclipse luna version 4.4.0. When I have installed numpy module using pip, it has got installed in python 2.7 site packages. I wanted to install it for python 3.5 and access from eclipse. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip3 for python3 packages.

```
pip3 install numpy
```